# Fully removing something from an Outlook 365 Calendar

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api

We have a Microsoft Graph V1.0 API integration to a company calendar. Recently a number of events were created in my calendar erroneously, inviting other members of the company as attendees. I now need to remove these.

I already accept there is no way to remove these without (another) e-mail being sent to all the attendees (thanks for that Outlook)... but *even when* I delete them using the API (or the UI for that).. the event remains in the former-attendees calendar - in strikethrough, and as "cancelled"... meaning their days will look something like this:

[image: vertical view]

and

[image: tile view]

This is obviously sub-optimal.

Is there any attribute or process I can follow to just completely remove these from the users calendar? All I can see from testing is that they can then go and open the event and "remove it" from their calendar by hand; this won't wash!

I'm currently deleting the events using the $batch endpoint with requests along the lines of

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "method": "DELETE",
      "url": "users/me/calendar/events/BiG1ongHa5HedID="
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there anything more brutal than using the event endpoint and the DELETE verb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Deleting an event that has attendees via the API behaves the same way as deleting it with Outlook. You're deleting the copy of the event on your calendar, and no one else's. You'd need access to each attendee's calendar and would need to make a separate API call to each of their calendars to remove it.